# how to read vmc push log

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

when i use vmc push project to micro cloudfoundry,start application error,
smart tips is below. but i can't find log is my project path.

```
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Processing resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (206K): OK   
Push Status: OK
Stopping Application: OK
Staging Application: OK                                                         
Starting Application: ..........................Error 306: Error retrieving file 'logs/startup.log'
```

where can found the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran `vmc push` to deploy the app. You **should** be able to run `vmc logs myapp` to see the logs.

But I have never seen a 306 error like that. I fear that `vmc logs myapp` might fail for the same underlying reason you got during push.

You should be able to ssh to the Micro Cloud Foundry instance and then track down the logs. They'll be here:

```
/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/myapp-a-bunch-of-other-letters-and-digits/tomcat
```

Comment: i deploy lift application.i don't know why cause a 306 error.i push pocketchange it cause that tip

`Creating Application: Error 702: External URIs are not enabled for this account`

Answer (score 2):

You can also manually look at files (such as logs) by using `vmc files <myapp> path/to/file`. For example:

`vmc files myapp logs/stderr.log`